# about incress crystalreports data point

Tags: c#

i get error while generating report "this chart cannot be displayed. It can process at most 32000 data points but 34534 points are being requested" please help me out to set 60000 data point into crystalreports in c#.net thank you!

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Information is missing in order to be able to help you. You should go over the tour as suggested by @Jan